# distance, inaccurate gps on Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, distance

i am creating a app which uses google maps v2 and gps to calculate the distance the user had walked. there are 2 issues. 
my gps is inaccurate. it does not show exactly where i am although the surrounding is correct. on road, buildings etc. but the place it is shown seem to be a bit off from the exact spot.
the way it update the location is after a few seconds the blue dot will "jump" from place to place. instead of moving smoothly and shows a line where the user has run.
my distance is inaccurate as. i need to press start moving to display the distance. after sometimes i press it the app crash. the count value is for me to determine where has the app run through in my code. according to how i planned it, the count should keep increasing as the distance keep increasing as well. 
sorry if there is a hug bunch of information but i thought i should provide more information. i search on the internet but could not find a way to calculate accurate distance or improve gps accuracy

this is my gps screenshot
[image]

My Main Activity Java code

```
import com.example.mypp.R; 
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener, Runnable{

protected LocationManager locationManager;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
Button btnStartMove,btnPause,btnResume,btnStop;
TextView Distance;
static double n=0;
    Long s1,r1;
    double lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2;
    double dis=0.0;
    MyCount counter;
    Thread t1;
    EditText e1;
    boolean bool=false;
    int count=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(isGooglePlay())
    {
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }
    btnStartMove=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Start);//start moving
    btnPause=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Pause);//pause
    btnResume=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Resume);//resume
    btnStop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Stop);
    Distance=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Distance);
    btnStartMove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //start(v);
            Distance.setText("Distance:" + dis);
            start(v);
    }

    });
    btnPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //start(v); 
        }
    });
    btnResume.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //start(v); 
        }
    });
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //start(v); 
        }
    });
}



private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    if(googleMap == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Getting map",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        googleMap =((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.displayMap)).getMap();

        if(googleMap != null)
        {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }

}

private void setUpMap() 
{
    //Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    //Get locationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    //LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    //Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    //Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if(provider == null)
    {
        onProviderDisabled(provider);
    }
    //set map type
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    //Get current location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if(myLocation != null)
    {
        onLocationChanged(myLocation);
    }       
}

private boolean isGooglePlay() 
{
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google Play Services is available",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return(true);
    }
    else
    {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 10).show();

    }
    return (false);

 }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location myLocation) {
    //Get latitude of the current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    //Get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
    //Create a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    //Show the current location in Google Map
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    //Zoom in the Google Map
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!"));

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void start (View v){

    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.Start:
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null)
        {
            lat2=location.getLatitude();
            lon2=location.getLongitude();
            bool=true;
            t1=new Thread(this);
            t1.start();
            counter= new MyCount(30000,1000);
            counter.start();

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "null location",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     break;
    case R.id.Pause:
        counter.cancel();
        bool=false;
        break;
    case R.id.Resume:
        counter= new MyCount(s1,1000);
     counter.start();
     bool=true;
     break;
    case R.id.Distance:
        double time=n*30+r1;
        Distance.setText("Distance:" + dis);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"distance in metres:"+String.valueOf(dis)+"Velocity in m/sec :"+String.valueOf(dis/time)+"Time :"+String.valueOf(time),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Value of Count:" + String.valueOf(count),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     break;        
    case R.id.Stop:
        counter.cancel();
        counter= new MyCount(30000,1000);
        bool = false;

    }
}

public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        counter= new MyCount(30000,1000);
     counter.start();
     n=n+1;
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        s1=millisUntilFinished;
        r1=(30000-s1)/1000;
        e1.setText(String.valueOf(r1));


    }
}

public double getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double latA = Math.toRadians(lat1);
    double lonA = Math.toRadians(lon1);
    double latB = Math.toRadians(lat2);
    double lonB = Math.toRadians(lon2);
    double cosAng = (Math.cos(latA) * Math.cos(latB) * Math.cos(lonB-lonA)) +
                    (Math.sin(latA) * Math.sin(latB));
    double ang = Math.acos(cosAng);
    double dist = ang *6371;
    return dist;
}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    count=6;
    //LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    lat1=location.getLatitude();
    lon1=location.getLongitude();
    while(bool==true)
    {
        if(lat1!=lat2 || lon1!=lon2)
        {
            dis+=getDistance(lat2,lon2,lat1,lon1);
            lat2=lat1;
            lon2=lon1;
            count =7;
            Distance.setText("Distance: " + dis + " Count: " + count);
            count++;
        }

    }

}}
```

sorry that i forgot to past the crash log. here it is. i know my code is a lot and confusing but i do not know of a efficient way to calculate distance.

```
01-28 00:36:58.820: D/dalvikvm(25535): GC_CONCURRENT freed 595K, 8% free 14911K/16135K, paused 4ms+8ms, total 56ms
01-28 00:37:06.135: D/TextLayoutCache(25535): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[0] is 30
01-28 00:37:06.135: D/TextLayoutCache(25535): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[0] is 30
01-28 00:37:06.135: D/TextLayoutCache(25535): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[1] is 2e
01-28 00:37:06.135: D/TextLayoutCache(25535): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[0] is 30
01-28 00:37:06.135: D/TextLayoutCache(25535): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[1] is 2e
01-28 00:37:06.135: D/TextLayoutCache(25535): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[2] is 30
01-28 00:37:06.135: D/TextLayoutCache(25535): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[0] is 30
01-28 00:37:06.135: D/TextLayoutCache(25535): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[0] is 30
01-28 00:37:06.135: D/TextLayoutCache(25535): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[1] is 2e
01-28 00:37:06.135: D/TextLayoutCache(25535): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[0] is 30
01-28 00:37:06.135: D/TextLayoutCache(25535): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[1] is 2e
01-28 00:37:06.135: D/TextLayoutCache(25535): TextLayoutCache::replaceThai, prevBuffer[2] is 30
01-28 00:37:06.140: D/AndroidRuntime(25535): Shutting down VM
01-28 00:37:06.140: W/dalvikvm(25535): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4178f2a0)
01-28 00:37:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(25535): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 00:37:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(25535): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 00:37:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(25535):    at com.example.studenthealthapp.MainActivity$MyCount.onTick(MainActivity.java:262)
01-28 00:37:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(25535):    at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:124)
01-28 00:37:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(25535):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 00:37:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(25535):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 00:37:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(25535):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
01-28 00:37:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(25535):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 00:37:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(25535):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 00:37:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(25535):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
01-28 00:37:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(25535):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
01-28 00:37:06.140: E/AndroidRuntime(25535):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 00:37:14.305: I/Process(25535): Sending signal. PID: 25535 SIG: 9
```

Comment: you question is not clear, also there is way to much code, also you mention a crash, but provide not stacktrace relative to this crash.

Answer (score 0):

to get the distance use [Location.distanceBetween](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29)

also you should be using the new Location API and not the old one. then you can set the minimum distance traveled to try to get rid of the GPS sending back incorrect locations

Comment: what is the new Location API? i only know of a different version of Google Map, i didn't know there is a new Location API..but the distance between is calculating the minimum straight distance between the starting and ending point? or do i use that to accumulate distance as new location changed. sorry but there is not much tutorial on distanceTo and distanceBetween. that's why i switch to manual calculation.

Comment: based on your link. how do i calculate the distance after i send in the parameters?

Comment: you keep a running total or keep a list of all the locations and then at the end loop through them getting the distance from point to point. The new location API is in google play services http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with tyczj that you should update to the latest google play location API and one of the main reasons is that they have dramatically improved the accuracy of location measurements and a second reason is that they have dramatically simplified the process of getting location data.

I have been working on an open source gps tracker project for several years. I recently updated it to handle periodic updates from android, ios, windows phone and java me cell phones. It is fully functional and does what you need and is MIT licensed.

https://github.com/nickfox/GpsTracker

Take a look at the android client. There are also two server stacks to choose from.

Comment: Does it give accurate distance?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this methods to find distance in meter... i have used this one and working fine for me...

/**
     * 
     * @param lat1
     *            Latitude of the First Location
     * @param lng1
     *            Logitude of the First Location
     * @param lat2
     *            Latitude of the Second Location
     * @param lng2
     *            Longitude of the Second Location
     * @return distance between two lat-lon in float format
     */

```
public float distFrom(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2)
{
    double earthRadius = 3958.75;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2 - lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2))
            * Math.sin(dLng / 2) * Math.sin(dLng / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double dist = earthRadius * c;

    int meterConversion = 1609;
    return new Float(dist * meterConversion).floatValue();
}

// This function converts decimal degrees to radians :::
private double deg2rad(double deg)
{
    return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}

// This function converts radians to decimal degrees :::
private double rad2deg(double rad)
{
    return (rad / Math.PI * 180.0);
}
```